# Lowercase Property Names

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am adding a document to Cosmos DB with following line:

```
client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, report).Wait();
```

My c# classes are uppercase however standard json you lowercase properties. Is it possible somehow to ensure this when saving the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the `DocumentClient` constructors accept an object called `JsonSerializerSettings`.

You can provide a different contract resolver there. In your case it's the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.

```
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(""), "", serializerSettings: new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    });
```